# Want to open link inside pop up on same page?

Tags: javascript

I want to open a Link inside popup window on same page.what yet I achieved is pop-up is opening on same page but when I used the iframe inside popup to open link its not going to work properly. help me

This content is opening inside popup window..

```
<div id="myModal" class="reveal-modal_global_data">
  <div id="wrapper-header_myModal">
    <h4>&nbsp;Experiment: Depth of Processing Global Results</h4>
  </div>
  <input type="submit" class="CSV_button" name="Expand All Activities" value="Download data in CSV Format" ></input>
  <iframe src="http://www.google.com" height="240px" width="286px">click here</iframe>
    <a class="close-reveal-modal">&#215;</a>
  </div>
```

what I want is like open google link inside that same popup..

Comment: have a look at the code

Comment: You cannot open Google inside of IFRAME - it doesn't allow it.

Comment: No i dnt want to  open google link its different link..but i Want to open that link inside same popup..

Comment: have you tried with some other link???

Comment: What is the other link and what exactly doesn't work with it?

Comment: umm nop wait ill check

Comment: yes..the link I want is opening inside popup window but now I dnt want the scroll bar n all of frame.. it sholud look like the line is opns in popup window

Comment: That's a different question and you should do more research before posting here (at least run your own code). That said try adding `scrolling="no"` to your IFRAME declaration